# Opening file in /public with browser part of tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a tutorial I am following it tells me the following:

```
In the terminal you can run

    $ ruby page_generator.rb

This will loop through all the files in the `views` directory, parse their erb and write the contents to the `public` directory.

Run the generator and drag a page from the `public` directory to your browser, it should render.
```

When I run the

```
$ ruby page_generator.rb
```

I get:

```
================================================
=== Converting files in /views to html =========
================================================
- Reading views/index.html.erb
  - Converting .html.erb to html
  - Writing public/index.html
- Reading views/me.html.erb
  - Converting .html.erb to html
  - Writing public/me.html
================================================
=== Done, open files in /public with browser ===
================================================
```

I am unsure what "open files in /public with browser" means? I've tried dragging, running the server(localhost), not sure what I'm supposed to do to get it to render on my browser? Any insight into what the tutorial is trying to tell me to do?

Comment: File > Open `public/index.html` with your web browser. You don't need a server to load static html files.

Comment: Thanks this helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should refer to the `public/` folder located inside the root folder of your Rails application; try to look there

Comment: But how do I open that? I see it, I just don't know how to render it? What do I type in my browser or what commands do I give?

Comment: Ahh i figured it out! I just had to open the file from my folders not sure why that never occurred to me. thanks!